# Call to a member function watermark() in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to add watermark to the existing image.  Codeigniter provides such functionality under **image_lib** library. Based on the instruction given [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#watermarking-an-image) , i have done. Fatal error is displaying instead of the result.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function watermark() on null
>
> Filename: controllers/Imageman.php
>
> Line Number: 22

Code is

```
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_img']='images/images.jpg';
        $config['wm_text']='Hi welcome..!';
        $config['wm_type']='text';
        $config['wm_font_path']='./system/fonts/texb.ttf';
        $config['wm_font_size']='16';
        $config['wm_font_color']='ffffff';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment']='bottom';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment']='center';
        $config['wm_padding']='20';

        $this->load->library('Image_lib',$config);
        $this->Image_lib->watermark();
        if($this->Image_lib->watermark())
        {
            echo "Watermark added";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed";
        }
```

Comment: Make `Image_lib` lowercase, `$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);` and `$this->image_lib->watermark()`.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation, it uses:
`$config['source_image']` instead of `$config['source_img']`